# Weird behaviour with semicolon before function call in IPython and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I stumbled upon some strange behaviour using Jupyter Notebook and wondered what, if any, the purpose was. If you enter a semicolon before a function call, you get the result of applying the function to a string which reflects all the code after the function name. For example, if I do `;list('ab')` I get the result of `list("('ab')")` :

```
In [138]:    ;list('ab')
Out[138]:
['(', "'", 'a', 'b', "'", ')']
```

I'm using Jupyter with IPython 4. It happens in IPython as well as Jupyter Notebook.

Is it intended and, if so, why?

Comment: This is a generic ipython thing and not specific to notebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a command for automatic quoting of function arguments: *[Automatic parentheses and quotes](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses-and-quotes)*

From the documentation:

> You can force automatic quoting of a function’s arguments by using ,
> or ; as the first character of a line. For example:

```
In [1]: ,my_function /home/me  # becomes my_function("/home/me")
```

> If you use ‘;’ the whole argument is quoted as a single string, while
> ‘,’ splits on whitespace:

```
In [2]: ,my_function a b c    # becomes my_function("a","b","c")

In [3]: ;my_function a b c    # becomes my_function("a b c")
```

> Note that the ‘,’ or ‘;’ MUST be the first character on the line! This
> won’t work:

```
In [4]: x = ,my_function /home/me # syntax error
```

In your case, it's quoting all characters, including `'` and `(` and `)`.

You get similar output here, but without the single quotes:

```
In [279]:
;list(ab)

Out[279]:
['(', 'a', 'b', ')']
```